# Microsoft Access 2002 Built In Query Logic Broken

Tags: ms-access

Recently I've been rolling out a fairly basic database migration for a client who happens to be using Microsoft Access XP on Windows 7 Professional. Overall the program was able to handle letting me prototype the full database solution, however now when I try to do a full trial run on a clone of the database - I keep getting compile errors, data type mismatches, and complete failures when running the queries I prepared.

I've done extensive searching and I'm familiar with the issue of missing references - however in my copy of Access, nothing is missing and when I tried the method of unchecking and rechecking the working references the problem still remained.

In particular this issue has been coming up with the Left() and Now() functions of Access - although as I can't work through the entire program now, it is possible other functions are not working.

Since I am running Windows 7, could this all be due simply because of UAC and the enhanced permission controls? If necessary I could try a test install of Access XP in Windows XP mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access XP [is no longer officially supported by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean21/en). From personal experience, I can tell that it was unstable under Vista already, so I'd bet that this has not improved with Windows 7.

Recommend your customer to switch to Office 2010, which officially supports Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I moved the databases over to my own system and everything ran flawlessly so it looks like that was a significant issue.

Comment: That is interesting to know. I have never actually come across anyone using Office 2002/XP, because it had a very short shelf life. It was also the first version with Macro Security, so perhaps it was rushed out because of this. Usually new releases of Office come out every 3 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to use the Left function in VBA modules in Access, because it is also a property of many objects. It is better to use the Mid function instead. You can also use Date instead of Now, though I am not sure why that would be necessary.

I doubt if your problems would be anything to do with UAC, but switching from 32-bit to 64-bit Windows can certainly cause problems. By far the biggest issue when deploying any Access database is Macro Security, but I am sure you are aware of that.

Also, make sure that you are not mixing DAO and ADO. That would certainly mess you up.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Although it wasn't the exact problem in this case, I'll defiantly keep it in mind with any other projects I take on involving Access development.